# Is it possible to combine two or more different highstock charts into one?

Tags: types, charts, highcharts

I would like to combine two chart types into one. For instance I would like to have at the top the candlestick (http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume) and underneath it the column range (http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/columnrange)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, take look at the example: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

Comment: Thanks but that is not exactly what I am after. What I would like to do is to combine different chart types into one. Like i said above:(http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume) with (http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/columnrange).